# Bazel: How to exclude path from code coverage for Scala / Java?

Tags: bazel, bazel-java

I am using Bazel with `rules_scala`. My problem now is how to exclude files from code coverage. So far this is how I am running coverage:

```
rm -rf coverage
bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator="@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main" ... 
genhtml -o coverage --ignore-errors source bazel-out/_coverage/_coverage_report.dat
```

But there are some folders I would like to exclude from code coverage. I tried using the `--instrumentation_filter` flag, but no matter what I tried putting there Bazel still collect coverage for this folder.

Are there any examples how I should use this flag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
bazel coverage --combined_report=lcov --coverage_report_generator="@bazel_tools//tools/test/CoverageOutputGenerator/java/com/google/devtools/coverageoutputgenerator:Main" -- //... -//package/to/ignore/...
```

Comment: Tried that with the complete target and it didn't worked...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug with `rules_scala`. See this [issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/15167) for more details.